# Docker swarm and ec2, how to advertise external ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-swarm

Is it possible to run docker swarm spanning across multiple physical networks? When I try to run a swarm in AWS ec2 instances, and advertise the public IP on `docker swarm init --advertise-addr` I get the error

```
Error response from daemon: must specify a listening address because the address to advertise is not recognized as a system address
```

However, when I advertise the private IP, everything works fine. Why is this? Is it not possible to run swarm accross different subnets?

Comment: following the question

Answer (score 0):

I ran through the same issue when Deploying Docker Swarm on AWS. I would advice you to deploy your nodes by specifying your public IP / Elastic IPs:

Instance A - Master node - Elastic IP 1.1.1.1

Instance B - Master node - Elastic IP 2.2.2.2

You want to use this command to join as a second master node from Instance B by using a manager token:

```
docker swarm --token SWMTKN-1-3pu6hszjas19xyp7ghgosyx9k8atbfcr8p2is99znpy26u2lkl-7p73s1dx5in4tatdymyhg9hu2 1.1.1.1:2377 --listen-addr 2.2.2.2
```